# Windows XP Mode on Windows 7

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc, windows-xp-mode

Is it normal to have a Windows XP Mode folder in a Windows 7 Pro, Program Files Directory? I see this key: K49H2-RPR94-QBGG4-DBCTM-YT64G. And I see the VXPEULA.txt file with EULA. Window XP Mode has never intentionally, or knowingly, been installed.

I also see Windows XP Mode base.vhd file that, by looking at properties, seems to be a virtual machine hard drive image.It looks like it should show up in Programs and Features to uninstall. I deleted the file when I was unable to find it in Programs and Features.

Also, I am unable to remove the virtual machine because it does not exist under any of the User names.

When I attempt to remove Windows Virtual PC, it does not exist in the installed updates.

To summarize, Windows XP Mode was not visible to uninstall so I deleted the file Windows XP Mode base.vhd; unable to remove Virtual Machine because it does not exist under any of the user names; and Virtual PC does not exist under installed updates.

Any thoughts as to why Windows XP Mode is on my computer? And does this sound a bit odd regarding the removal?

Comment: Is this an OEM install of Windows 7 you are using, or did you install Windows 7 yourself?

Comment: Yes, this is an OEM install of Windows 7 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal.

As Izam indirectly pointed when asked if you installed Windows 7 yourself or if it's an OEM install (or factory reset), maybe it was captured when the OEM built the repair/factory reset image.

I would install Windows 7 from scratch, but you can also install Windows XP Mode again and then uninstall, so to avoid any leftovers on your system besides the Windows XP Mode folder you found.